# Proper way to use multiple python processes in GUI application accessing underlying data store?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm strictly a python script writer, only ever done one-off scripts. Mainly for string manipulation etc. However, I consider myself proficient enough to be able to handle (with much searching) most of the implementation details of what I want to do (most of which is already done in various scripts).

My current project would involve a UI (let's assume in PyQT, I have not decided but probably wouldn't go with tkinter) which displays data. I haven't done the UI as my scripts so far have all be command-line.

I'd like there to be a separate process which handles the updating of said data. The data store would be a bunch of XML files (unfortunately this is a requirement of the project[1]). Due to the unbounded number of XML files potentially available, I think a separate process would prevent my UI getting locked. In my language of choice (C++ with QT) I'd just use threading, but reading about the GIL it seems I should instead use processes.

My current idea is for one process which reads the XML files and potentially encodes them in some convenient format for my UI process. This process would probably also monitor the data store for any possible file additions/deletions/modifications. Finally, in the encoding process, I probably also want to maintain an index of search terms to increase responsiveness. I expect fairly heavy computational load in this process, which is why I intend to split it off. A full scan of my current data store (not yet doing all the processing I would want) takes about half a second, and I plan to grow it.

The UI process accepts user input (for example, a search term) and displays the necessary results. There will also be a slight amount of processing, but nothing taxing. The user may also choose to save the record she's currently viewing, but I'm undecided whether the actual file change should be done by the UI process or it should be handed off to the background process.

In conclusion:-

1. What's the best way to share what I presume will be a large-ish python object between my processes? Is it queues, pipes, writing/reading to a separate database object, or something else?
2. I'm operating on the assumption that the UI process needs the ENTIRE data store. In practice, it possibly only needs a summary (think client-server architecture between UI process and data store process), but this would of course involve more overhead coding/maintenance wise. Is this considered good practice for an application which will always only run on one device?

Additional information:-
[1] - Requirement for XML files is because they are easily shared between devices via file-sync services such as dropbox etc. in a reasonably atomic manner. Since this project requires record-based synchronization, including allowing simultaneous edits (post-merging is possible) in different machines, I'd rather let the third party file-sync service handle it than write my own buggy synchronization tool. Also, and most crucially, there are already users of this data store using it in its current XML form, so it would be extremely difficult to change it.